# How to remove whitespace from a expression using a function with const char* pointer

Tags: c++

I am working with a small piece of code and want to remove all the whitespaces from a simple expression. I am taking char array expression and passing it to an function with const char* pointer,but i am not able to remove the whitespace. here is what i tried, but didn't get desired output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void evaluate(const char *expression){

if (*expression == '\0') cout<<"Invalid"<<endl;

while(*expression){
    if(*expression == ' '){
        *expression++ ;
    }
    expression++;
 }

cout<<expression;

}

int main()
{
    char expr[] = "1 + 2 * 3";
    evaluate(expr);
    return 0;
}
```

It will be great if someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: `std::string` - simplify your life.

Comment: The code detects the space, but does nothing useful when it does. Stop coding and  determine what you really need to do in `if(*expression == ' '){ what goes here? }` before continuing.

Comment: If your intent is just to output without spaces, then `while (*expression) { if (*expression != ' ') cout << (char)*expression; expression++; } cout << '\n';`

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void evaluate(const char *expression){
    if (*expression == '\0') std::cout << "Invalid\n";

    std::cout << expression;
}

int main()
{
    char expr[] = "1 + 2 * 3";
    std::string exprString = expr;
    exprString.erase(
        std::remove(std::begin(exprString), std::end(exprString), ' '),
        std::end(exprString));
    evaluate(exprString.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I added string but I recommend to completely remove the C-strings in this code and replace them by std::string.

You can't change the C-string inside the function because it's const.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent is simply to output the expression without spaces when calling  `evaluate()`, you can simplify things by outputting each character that is not a space with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void evaluate (const char *expression) {

    if (!*expression) {
        cout << "Invalid\n";
        return;
    }

    while (*expression) {
        if (*expression != ' ')
            cout << (char)*expression;
        expression++;
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main() {

    char expr[] = "1 + 2 * 3";

    evaluate(expr);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rmws_const_char
1+2*3
```

Comment: Why the cast to `char` at `cout`?

Comment: No need here, habit really from dealing with `int c` from `getchar();`, etc.. Since the elements are already `char`, you are correct here -- the cast is superfluous, but harmless.

Answer (score 0):

```
*expression++
```

This only increments the pointer (and needlessly evaluates what it was pointing at). It does *not* modify the original character array.

If you want the expression in memory without spaces, rather than just for output purposes, I suggest that you build a new array with the spaces removed.